# I answered 13 out of 30 questions correctly; why is my percentile 37?

Tags: quantiles

I did an online test, and i got the below results:

```
Total questions: 30
Number of correct: 13
Number incorrect: 17
scored: 43.3 
percentile: 37
```

My question is, how did they calculate the percentile?
Now, I know that 13/30 * 100 give me the score 43.3

But how can we get the 37?

Please for more clarification see the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: Percentile compares how you did to other people who took the same test. You scored better than 37% of people who took this test. To put it another way, 63% of people had a score better than 13/30.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The interpretation appears to be: You got 13/30. 37% of people did worse, 63% did better. There is some small print on how people who got exactly the same mark as you were treated, but a better approximation might be 37% is the % of people who did worse PLUS half of the % of people who got the same mark while 63 % is the rest.

Comment: What i got from your answer is that I can't calculate the percentile by myself . Since it comes from the total average people scores. Is that right?

Comment: Indeed. You need to know the other scores to work out where you stand.

Answer (score 3):

The interpretation appears to be:

First, you got 13/30 answers correct. That is 43.3% to 1 decimal place.

What does **percentile** mean here?

*Crude summary:* 37% of people did worse, 63% did better.

*Better summary:* It's a fair guess that many people got exactly the same score as you, so how does that work? We can't tell from what you show exactly what the procedure was, but one systematic way to proceed would be that

1. 37% is the % of people who did worse PLUS half of the % of people who got the same mark
2. Correspondingly, 63% is the % of people who did better PLUS the other half of the % who got the same mark.

Ties of this kind will be common whenever the sample size is not tiny and we're counting correct answers or measuring to a fixed resolution, as we usually are.

Somebody needs to know the distribution of all marks to make the calculation. You can't do it from what you're told.

Note that historically, and some would say correctly, it is 43.3% that is a particular percentile, as percentiles are counted or measured in the units of the data. So 37% should then be called something different, say the **percentile rank** or the **cumulative probability**. Equivocation (sloppiness?) of this kind is common, and people are often expected to tell from context what means what.

So, it's just an accident that the numbers in your case are similar, 43.3% versus 37%. For example, the 37% percentile of adult male height in any country will be 1.something metres, so there confusion is unlikely. Yet again, percentiles for heights in inches could be confusing....